# How do you bridge route (broute) just ipv6 from a single interface to an existing bridge?

Tags: routing, bridge

The setup that prompted this question and the solution below to make life simpler for the next person.

I have a dd-wrt router. It bridges eth1, eth2, and vlan1. It routes them through vlan2 which has the wan port. My understanding absolutely sucks at ipv6, or the dd-wrt router, or both. I have T-mobile as an isp. Their ipv6 is great, until you try to run it through your own router, then that /64 they give you blows. If I let their device handle DHCP everything works: ipv4, ipv6. Problem is I need to be able to configure DHCP addresses for certain devices. It doesn't have any way to do that.

in a more visual format:

```
vlan2 (internet)(routed) -> br0 (bridge of: eth1, eth2, vlan1)
```

So the solution seems to be bridging ipv6 and routing ipv4. Credit to this question for that info: https://serverfault.com/questions/322718/can-i-bridge-ipv4-while-routing-ipv6-on-the-same-two-interfaces

In more visual format again:

```
ipv4: vlan2 (internet)(routed) -> br0 (bridge of: eth1, eth2, vlan1)
ipv6: br0 (bridge of: eth1, eth2, vlan1, vlan2)
```

However trying to bridge a bridge gives you this error:

```
device br0 is a bridge device itself; can't enslave a bridge device to a bridge device.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i vlan2 -p ! ipv6 -j DROP && brctl addif br0 vlan2
```

Source: http://blog.iopsl.com/ipv6-behind-openwrt-router/

I came back to change this answer because my solution was crap, and I thought it worked but it had a lot of problems. This works much better. Basically you bridge the two connections. Then route everything that isn't ipv6